# Separated all bootstrap css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible i get separated css file for bootstrap component for example in my project i only need for **bootstrap tooltip** so can i download bootstrap-tooltip file.i don't want to add **bootstrap.min.css** file i only need tooltip css file.

i don't want to use

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i want something like bootstap-tooltip.min.css

because i used other plugin which have same class as bootstrap so it's take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you can customize boostrap also:

Follow this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Here you can generate your own bootstrap configuration using LESS files.

Choose what you want and need and scroll down to the end of page. Press the button `Compile and Download` and your done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the codepen only for bootstrap tooltip:

[check here](https://codepen.io/dinglestein/pen/ikDoh)

SCSS

```
    $alphablack:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

body {
  margin:5em;
}

[data-tooltip] {
  &:hover {
    &:before, &:after {
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      font-size:0.8em;
      color:white;
    }
    &:before {
      border-radius:0.2em;
      content:attr(title);
      background-color:$alphablack;
      margin-top:-2.5em;
      padding:0.3em;
    }
    &:after {
      content:'';
      margin-top:-2.1em;
      margin-left:1em;
      border-style:solid;
      border-color:transparent;
      border-top-color:$alphablack;
      border-width:0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    }
  }
}
```